# problems on java to javascript communication using SWT browser

Tags: javascript, java, html, swt, jface

Hi i am using a swt browser in my program, from javascript i am accessing a method defined in java,

```
new CustomFunction(browser, "theJavaFunction");
```

**For Full Example Click Here** http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/

I am able to access java method from javascript and it is returning a string back. But the browser object is being hanged up while the control going to java, the browser is becoming idle. In my case i am taking some time for processing  in java.  I have used a spinner GIF image in browser to show it is processing but because of this problem the spinner is also not working. Please Help.

Comment: Give broader context of code. I dont understand what your one line has to do with vegeela blog (very good blog BTW)

Comment: As far as I understand your scenario this is no particular problem of the Javascript to Java interaction  You are invoking Java code and if this code performs a long running task it will block the calling thread i.e. the UI thread. To keep your UI responsive you will have to spawn a thread that performs the long running task.